# IDictionary and Connection.RetrieveStatistics .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net

I see code like the following in several books and examples online. The problem is they all feed in a single method into a dictionary object which requires two.

```
IDictionary statistics = connection.RetrieveStatistics();
```

Which returns the IDE error:

```
Error   1   Using the generic `type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey,TValue>' requires '2' type arguments   C:\Users\SGM7\Documents\ASPX 3_5 book code\Pro ASP.NET 3.5\Chapter07\Website\Tester.aspx.cs 22  9   C:\...\Website\`
```

So even though connection.RetrieveStatistics() returns pairs, how can I get IDictionary to accept connection.RetrieveStatistics()?

Here's the code block.

```
connection.Open();
connection.StatisticsEnabled = true;

IDictionary statistics = connection.RetrieveStatistics();

lblBytes.Text = "Received bytes: " + statistics["BytesReceived"].toString();
connection.Close();
lblBytes.Text += connection.State.ToString();
```

Comment: Apart from the lower-case "t" in "toString", your code compiles and runs fine for me (once I declare and initialize "connection"). Can you add any more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on RetrieveStatistics in your code block in VS and pick 'go to definition' to see how it is defined.  My guess is it's a System.Collections.IDictionary, not a System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<K,V>.

Or, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, use var:

```
var statistics = connection.RetrieveStatistics();
```

Comment: Ah yes! If I remove the "using System.Collections" I get the same compile error he describes. Good one!

Comment: Thank you. Figured it had to be something simple, else why would there be so many examples using that code. I just fully qualified it and it ran.

Answer (score 1):

The compile error makes it looks like you're trying to use a generic dictionary instead of a non-generic Dictionary.

The return type of `RetrieveStatistics()` is `IDictionary`, not `IDictionary<T,K>`

Do you have a using declaration that's mapping `IDictionary` to something else?  Have you tried using `System.Collections.IDictionary` explicitly?

For example:

```
System.Collections.IDictionary statistics = connection.RetrieveStatistics();
```

As Jonathan says, `var` will also work, because the compiler will just figure out what the type should be.